# An application to easily pick a color in Mac OS X and get the hex value

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, colors

I'm looking for a way to easily pick a color from anywhere on the screen in Mac OS X and get the value as a hex code (like #ACC782 ).

OS X has a built in system "color picker" and I found a [standalone "app"](http://robinwood.com/Catalog/Technical/OtherTuts/MacColorPicker/MacColorPicker.html#colorPickerApp) that will just run that, but I don't see any way to get the hex code from it.

Firefox and Chrome both have "color picker" extensions but I'm looking for something that I can use on any application.

What can I use for that? It would be really nice if it automatically copied the value to the clipboard, but that may be asking too much :)

[image]

Comment: You do realize that you didn't need to register a second account to answer your questions, but can simply answer them with your own account (like e.g. I do)?

Comment: I asked a moderator about it; if you want, they could merge your accounts. There is no rule against answering your own questions. (Assuming you are haxie)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

OS X comes with DigitalColor Meter:

Applications > Utilities > DigitalColor Meter.app

It has many options and preferences.

command+shift+c will copy the color under the cursor to the clipboard in many different formats.

Comment: Just to add you can get the output in hex by going to View->Display values->Hexadecimal

Comment: I tried command+shift+c but it does not copies the values in mountain lion. Update: We have to keep the DigitalColor Meter Selected, I would  click on the image expecting the keys to copy the color.

Comment: @broom, Where did the color picker go to?

Comment: @Pacerier Digital Color Meter is still available in macOS. I still see it in 10.15.4.

Comment: Wow this is so cool, it's still available for me as well. I didn't know MacOS came with this, they really did think of everything.

Comment: Can't believe I only just found this! 

Answer (score 11):

The Mac OS X color picker is extensible.

Use [Hex Color Picker](http://wafflesoftware.net/hexpicker/) to add a tab that provides you the configured color in hexadecimal RGB.

[image]

Just run e.g. TextEdit and press `Cmd-Shift-C` to open the color picker, or run your standalone program.

---

An even more versatile color picker is [Developer Color Picker](http://download.panic.com/picker/) with many different output formats, one of which is hexadecimal.

[image]

Comment: Can they pick color under cursor?

Comment: @Daniel, I dun get it.. Why not just use mac DigitalColor?

Comment: @Pacerier Because that's the option I was aware of and used at the time. Note that the latter has a number of additional features useful in many contexts you may want to use the color in.

Comment: The Mac DCM doesn't seem to work on full screen apps...

Answer (score 3):

This is easily done with AppleScript. A complete working example of code is [available here](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2011/12/29/colorpicker-applescript-for-mac-os-x/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old post, but just thought I'd throw this one out there that I've been using for awhile: [Sip](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/sip/id507257563?mt=12).  Works pretty sweet, and you can get a ton of different color options.

[App Store Link: Sip](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/sip/id507257563?mt=12)

I have no affiliation with the developer, just think it's a cool little app.  And it's Free!  :-)  Enjoy

Comment: I dun get it..What can Sip do that DigitalColor cant?

Comment: Granted... It works similar to DigitalColor. Where I've found differences is in the how the app functions over all.  Sip for instance has a lot more options in terms of what it can capture the color as; NSColor RGB, HSB, OpenGL RGB, Swift NSColor, UIColor RGB, CSS Hex, Java RGB, Android XML etc... just to name a few (30+ options in total).  Versus the six options that DC has.   Personally, I also like the history palette that stores some of my recent color pics, and that it sits up in the menu bar tucked away neatly.  Anyway, yeah, the both do (pretty much) the same thing.  I just prefer Sip.